# How do I mock a function within a functional component in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Trying to figure out how to mock a function that is inside a functional component Typescript React. Here is the code...

`HeaderBar.tsx`

```js
const HeaderBar: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<any>> = (props: any) => {
  const search = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };
};
```

`HeaderBar.test.tsx`:

```
import HeaderBar from './HeaderBar';
it('mocks the search function', () => {
   const wrapper = shallow(<HeaderBar />);
   const mock = jest.spyOn(HeaderBar, 'search');
})
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot spy the search property because it is not a function; undefined given instead.

I think it is because the function I want to test is inside of another function(i.e. functional component). I am not using classes, so I am wondering how I can mock this function?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock the function defined in SFC. And, we shouldn't test the implementation details of the functions. We should test the behaviour of the React Component. This is the test background and strategy for testing React Component.

So, the unit test for your sample code is:

`HeaderBar.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

const HeaderBar = (props: any) => {
  const search = e => {
    console.log(e);
  };
  return <div onClick={search}></div>;
};

export default HeaderBar;
```

`HeaderBar.test.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import HeaderBar from './HeaderBar';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('mocks the search function', () => {
  const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
  const wrapper = shallow(<HeaderBar />);
  const mEvent = { target: 'fake target' };
  wrapper.find('div').simulate('click', mEvent);
  expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith(mEvent);
});
```

We can spy on `console.log` and test if it is to be called. If there is `setState` in your function, you should use `wrapper.state()` to test state, assert it to your expected state.

Unit test with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57154476/HeaderBar.test.tsx
  ✓ mocks the search function (16ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    { target: 'fake target' }

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 HeaderBar.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.506s, estimated 9s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57154476